# How do I verify the GPG sig for Litecoin Core?

Tags: client, litecoin, mac

Usually I am able to verify signatures using the `verify` option in GPG, but this doesn't work when attempting to verify the Litecoin Core client DMG.

For example:

```
$ gpg --verify litecoin-0.14.2-osx.dmg.asc litecoin-0.14.2-osx.dmg
gpg: Signature made Mon Jul 31 14:44:45 2017 PDT
gpg:                using RSA key FE3348877809386C
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

I am using the GPG 2.2.3 install from Homebrew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did to get this to work

Copy the public key (found [here](https://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xFE3348877809386C)) to a file. I called it `litecoin.public.key`.

Then run the following commands:

```
gpg --import litecoin.public.key
gpg --verify litecoin-0.14.2-osx.dmg.asc litecoin-0.14.2-osx.dmg
```

This is the output that I got

```
gpg: Signature made Mon Jul 31 17:44:45 2017 EDT
gpg:                using RSA key FE3348877809386C
gpg: Good signature from "Adrian Gallagher <thrasher@addictionsoftware.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 59CA F0E9 6F23 F537 4794  5FD4 FE33 4887 7809 386C
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and import their PGP key. There is a link to it on litecoin.org's download page. You can also get it directly from a [keyserver](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xFE3348877809386C)

Comment: I have already downloaded the key, as I was able to run `--verify` on the .asc file. When trying the `--import` option, I get `$ gpg --import litecoin-0.14.2-osx.dmg.asc; gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.; gpg: Total number processed: 0`